# Shared Gmail account and privileges management

Tags: email, gmail

I'm working with a company from abroad and I get paid on commission upon customer creation. This means that till know I've been managing myself the company email, as I was afraid to get tricked (eg: If the company deals directly w the customer and deletes the emails, I wouldn't find out and wouldn't get paid).

My question is, have somebody of you worked sharing a single Gmail account? And if so, is there a way to set privileges in the account? Eg. user A and create, read and destroy, but user B can only create and read.

That way I could control the email flow and speed up the selling process, as right now when the customer ask a question that I can't answer, I have to contact the company, wait for the answer and answer back, which is a total mess.

Anyway, any light shed upon this particular issue would be more than appreciated!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a webmastering as defined in the FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**. This *might* be on-topic at [Web Applications](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help) before posting there.

Answer (score 1):

I have never shared an email account, so I don't have much experience with that aspect, although it seems like a bad idea. You should try to use some other system that allows all the involved parties to have a copy of each mail and documentation, may be some kind of [groupware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_software), or an application like basecamp or any other [alternative](http://pm-sherpa.com/features/basecamp-alternatives/) that better suits your needs.

In any case, you seem interested on reading this Google article about [Set up mail delegation](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350?hl=en&ctx=mail). It may help you.

> You can delegate access to your Gmail to another person so they can read, send, and delete messages on your behalf. For example, you can delegate e-mail rights to an admin in your organization, or you could delegate your personal email access to your spouse. The delegate can also access the other person's contacts by clicking the Contacts link. Clicking the To, Cc, or Bcc links in the mail compose window will also bring up your contacts.
>
> You won't be able to give anyone permission to change your account password or account settings, or chat on your behalf. You can specify up to 10 users. Google Apps for Business, Education, and Government customers can specify up to 25 users. Here's how:

If that is what you want, there are lots of pages out there with related information on how to enable and how to disable the delegation process. It may also be useful to [read a bit more about the delegation process, alternatives and other apps with related capabilities](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=site%3agoogle.com+gmail+delegation).